# Where does the WebHost variable come from in a .net core webapi project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Upon [creating a .Net Core webapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio-code) application, the following code is created:

```
namespace dotnet_testing
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

In the CreateWebHostBuilder function there is a WebHost object/variable that gets operated upon.  Where did that WebHost variable come from?  It's not passed into the function.  Is it a global variable?

I come from Javascript & PHP backgrounds and am new to C# & .Net Core.

Answer (score 0):

[WebHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost?view=aspnetcore-2.1), it's a static class:

> Provides convenience methods for creating instances of IWebHost and
>   IWebHostBuilder with pre-configured defaults.

See also [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Because of your response, I'm seeing now that it is a "static class".  So there's no instantiation of the class.  So WebHost is just available because of the "using Microsoft.AspNetCore;" statement at the top? ... I just don't quite get C# namespacing yet - its more obvious in php.

Comment: yes, and because it's in referenced assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll.